# 2 Column html page layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page layout that is basically a left navigation and a right data panel. Both of these will have header, content & footer. Content is scrollable.My html is

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav" ><header id='header'>NAV HEADER</header><div class="content-nav"></div><footer id='footer'>NAV FOOTER</footer></div>
    <div id="disp"><header id='header'>DATA HEADER</header><div class="content-data"></div></div>
</div>
```

Outer div container is position relative & both nav and disp are position absolute.
https://jsfiddle.net/7gqc6nyz/

I want the scrollable content of each to take full space between the header & footer. As seen in the jsfiddle when content is set height:100% it flows out of the outer container by header height, hence even when scroll to bottom not all content is see? I can user calc(100%-headerheight) but seems not elegant

Is there a better strategy than using positioning? Maybe flexboxing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your height to

```
.content-nav, .content-data {
            height: calc(100% - 80px);
            overflow:auto;
        }
```

And so easy. Take in count that may not work in older navigators, so if you want retro compatibility you have to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

a better positioning would be to use float instead of relative and absolute position.

add

```
float:left;
```

to the css of #nav and get rid of all position related css code should do the trick.

if you want same height for both divs just add

```
height:100%;
overflow: auto /* for scrolling */
```

on both divs' css